# sql function to add each row values

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor, procedure, func

table a

```
id
1
2
3
4
```

i want output to be like this:

```
id id_new
1   1
2   3 
3   6
4   10
```

basically we are adding row values of a column in each row
i.E 2=1+2 ,3=1+2+3 and so on
you can use any cursor,function or query

Comment: `sum(id)over(order by id)`

Answer (score 4):

You seem to want a cumulative sum.  The ANSI standard function is a window function, supported by Oracle:

```
select id, sum(id) over (order by id) as id_new
from t;
```

It seems strange to do this with a column called `id`, though.  Usually, cumulative sums are on counts or amounts or something measurable.

If you need to actually update the data, then you can use a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set id_new = (select sum(id) from t t2 where t2.id <= t.id);
```

This will work on a small table.  For anything larger, use `merge`.

Answer (score 4):

The comment by Pradeep is probably the way to go on Oracle.  But there is an alternative to that, which is using a correlated subquery to compute the rolling sum:

```
SELECT
    id,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.id) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.id <= t1.id) id_new
FROM yourTable t1;
```

This answer may have some merit because not every database supports analytic functions.  And even if we are using Oracle in the context of, e.g., a Java application, an ORM interface like JPA or Hibernate may not support analytic functions.

Comment: ha ha +1 for decoding my name ;)

Comment: @Pரதீப் I know it's you because previously your name was not in Tamil (and I know some Tamil because most of my coworkers are Tamilians :-) ).

Answer (score 2):

Piece of cake.

```
SQL> with test (id) as
  2  (select 1 from dual union
  3   select 2 from dual union
  4   select 3 from dual union
  5   select 4 from dual
  6  )
  7  select id, sum(id) over (order by id) id_new
  8  from test
  9  order by id;

        ID     ID_NEW
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          3
         3          6
         4         10

SQL>
```

**[EDIT, a *generalized* option]**

```
SQL> select level id, sum(level) over (order by level) new_Id
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= &n;
Enter value for n: 5
old   3: connect by level <= &n
new   3: connect by level <= 5

        ID     NEW_ID
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          3
         3          6
         4         10
         5         15

SQL> /
Enter value for n: 3
old   3: connect by level <= &n
new   3: connect by level <= 3

        ID     NEW_ID
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          3
         3          6

SQL>
```

Comment: make it a generalized query , for 1,2,3...n

Comment: Here you go, @sheetal